# 20.10: Getting notifications despite Do Not Disturb

Tags: notification, 20.10

I've enabled Do Not Disturb for notifications in Ubuntu 20.10 but I still get large notification popups in the top middle of the screen (as if that were the most out-of-the-way place to put them), telling me how much free storage I have left.

**How do I properly turn off notifications?**

DnD clearly doesn't work, and I can't find an off switch for notifications anywhere in system settings. I can't even identify which application is generating the notification since the notification 1) doesn't tell me its origin, and 2) its icon (a hard drive) does not correspond to any of those listed in system settings.

There's more than one notification with a distinct icon that doesn't correspond to an item in settings, so in reality I'm also struggling to deactivate other notifications whenever DnD is *not* active.

To be honest I don't think I understand anything about the notification system -- not even how to read the entire text of a notification that has been truncated (i.e. all of them). If I click on one I get sent away somewhere without knowing what it says, and if I right-click it nothing happens. I don't understand how I'm supposed to use them properly.

---

Update
Added a screenshot of a notification during DnD upon request:

[image: DnD on, notifications continue]

As you can see, DnD is on, but not respected.

Comment: Hmmm. DnD clearly does properly work for me on 20.10, so I suspect you might be asking the wrong question. How to turn off notifications seems like a counterproductive question -- some notifications are useful and important. Seems like you should be asking how to track down and uninstall that poorly-behaved application.

Comment: @user535733 Could you expand on why you think that?

Comment: @user535733 Ah, your answer is that it is wrong to want to turn off notifications. Got it.

Comment: @Andreas details on this notification you're seeing will be prudent.  If the notification is Critical like a low system space notice that *might* bypass DnD if it's issued with an older mechanism, but if you're getting 'low disk space' errors you have a bigger problem than just notifications.

Comment: @ThomasWard Absolutely, which details do you think would be helpful? If a screenshot is required I'll take one next time it appears. Meanwhile perhaps you know of a way to disable notifications in the absence of working DnD? I am not getting any errors, just unwanted notifications that don't appear to honor DnD.

Comment: @ThomasWard I added a screenshot for you

Comment: I face the same problem! Even when the not DnD option is on, it doesn' change anything: I have notifications from chrome, skype and any other program that sends its regular notifications. So no, nothing related to important notifications or not. The feature just doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 3):

Same here.
Ubuntu 21.04, 20.10 Gnome's "Do not disturb" does not work.
But I found something.

When "Do not disturb" is enabled, only `notify-send <message>` is disabled, other applications' notifications are not disabled.

So I had to disable all applications' notifications when I want "DnD".

For disabling all applications' notification, I made the following script.
Run the script at GNOME startup, after that whenever Gnome Shell "Do Not Disturb" status changed, the script enable/disable all applications' notification.

```
#!/bin/bash
function change_app_notification() {
    APPS=( $(dconf list "/org/gnome/desktop/notifications/application/") )
    declare -p APPS

    local enable=$1

    for app in "${APPS[@]}"
    do
        echo "$app 'enable' to -> $enable"
        dconf write "/org/gnome/desktop/notifications/application/${app}enable" $enable
        # show-banners has no effect
        # dconf write "/org/gnome/desktop/notifications/application/${app}show-banners" $enable
    done

}

# first sync current state
change_app_notification $(gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.notifications show-banners)

# monitoring show-banners value
while read line
do
    show_banners=$(echo $line | cut -d' ' -f2)
    echo "current gnome notifications show-banners : $show_banners"
    change_app_notification $show_banners
done < <(gsettings monitor org.gnome.desktop.notifications show-banners)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Does this save the current state of dconf notification enable setting for each app and restore after? What if I say separately disabled nofications for some chat app previously that I never want to see notifications even when DnD turns off, and then would this script turn it back on again?

Comment: @VijayPrema Nope. You have to add commands for your purpose.